# Interactive meshcat visualization

Tags: drake

I am trying to run the flip-up-box example interactively through the jupyter notebook, locally on my system. However, the `meshcat` visualization is running into the following trouble:

1. Geometries are loading up very slowly.
2. Even though I am changing the slider position to command a new `theta` for the box, the finger does not seem to be doing anything.

I also noticed that the bit of code that actually runs the simulation does not publish the animation anywhere (posted below). I was wondering what exactly happens here, and is there something that I need to change to get a smoother experience with meshcat? I realise that the meshcat experience question has been asked a few time and apologise for the duplication. The following snippet has been taken from the `point_finger.ipynb` in the manipulation exercises.

```
if not running_as_notebook:
        simulator.AdvanceTo(0.01)
    elif teleop:
        simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)
        meshcat.AddButton("Stop Simulation", "Escape")
        while meshcat.GetButtonClicks("Stop Simulation") < 1:
            simulator.AdvanceTo(simulator.get_context().get_time() + 2.0)
        meshcat.DeleteButton("Stop Simulation")
        meshcat.DeleteAddedControls()
    else:
        simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)
        simulator.AdvanceTo(traj.end_time() + 1.0)
```

Thank you for you help and instruction.

Comment: UPDATE: It turns out that the visualization is very slow to show the change in box angle. The finger indeed does flip the box. However, when I try to run the cell in jupyter repeatedly (making some debug changes - print statements etc.) the meshcat browser window becomes less responsive.